# Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'

Tags: java, gradle

После установки java 9 в командной строке видно, что java установлена:

```
C:\Users\Xu>java --version
java 9.0.1
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

Но когда я после этого пытаюсь выполнить команду `gradlew -v`, получаю следующее сообщение об ошибке:

```
C:\Users\Xu\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\bin>gradle --version --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'.
        at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.toVersion(JavaVersion.java:72)
        at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.current(JavaVersion.java:82)
        at org.gradle.internal.jvm.UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.assertUsingVersion(UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:253)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:182)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советуют обновить версию `gradle` до 4.2.1 или 4.3-rc-2

[источник discuss.gradle.org](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/could-not-determine-java-version-from-9-0-1/24457/2)

[источник английский SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432937/could-not-determine-java-version-from-9-0-1-intellij-windows)